# Generating Subtitles of a Youtube video when CC is not available

Tags: python, nlp, youtube

How to get subtitles of a youtube video when CC is not available (using python). Is there any library to make it possible?

I tried using youtube_transcript_api for YT videos that have CC. I want it for videos that do not have CC and I don't want to download the video for getting mp4 to text. I want it directly.

Comment: May you provide an example of YouTube video not having CC available?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmnCZ7-9yDY

Comment: I am not keen on that but if I were you I would download only the audio from the video using [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) and then use standard speech-to-text tools.

Comment: Ya, that's a good approach but, I thought of keeping it as a last choice. If I don't find any direct approach (using libraries), I may use that.